# Initializing final variable in java constructor

Tags: java, data-structures

Lets say I have a situation like this.

```
private final A a;
private final B b;
private final C c;
private ClassX(){
  this.c = createCSomehow();
}
public ClassX(A a){
  this();
  this.a = a;
  this.b = null;
}
public ClassX(B b) {
  this();
  this.b = b;
  this.a = null;
}
```

Why Idea is complaining about a and b property? Idea underline them and say: Variable a might not have been initialized. I am sure that I have no more constructors and that in every case a will be populated with some value.

Comment: Is it only Idea "complaining" or the compiler as well? IDE warnings are usually intended to help avoid incorrect code

Comment: I think it's because some code could call the private constructor and not have a nor b initialized.

Comment: `"in every case a will be populated with some value"` - Except in the case where the very first constructor you show in your code is used...

Comment: @David Yes but thats why I made my constructor private and I guess idea can figure that empty constructor is called only on this 2 places where I populate my fields. I used bad word. I had compilation error, not an warning.

Comment: @Spasoje: Just because something is private doesn't mean it can't be called at all in any possible situation.  That's what the compiler is telling you.  While it may not happen in your *expected* usage, there *does exist* a possibility that an instance of that object could be created with uninitialized values.  Even if it has to be created from within that class, it can still happen.

Comment: @David I expected that error for example if I made call to that constructor. But obviously in every constructor I must initialize all of my variables. Thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really know how to properly answer the *why* (JLS investigation needed), but for the *how*, the following should compile:

```
private final A a;
private final B b;
private final C c = createCSomehow();

public Main(A a){
  this.a = a;
  this.b = null;
}

public Main(B b) {
  this.b = b;
  this.a = null;
}
```

Comment: I think the why is because the first private constructor does not properly initialize the objects. Thus we have an improper (even if private) constructor.

Answer (score 6):

As per the JLS specs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2

A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned (§16.9) at the end of every constructor (§8.8) of the class in which it is declared; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.
This is why Idea is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, after leaving a constructor your final fields must be initialized. Hence provide one constructor which initializes all fields and reuse it by the `public` constructors to provide the concrete values. Like this code:

```
private ClassX(A a, B b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = createCSomehow();
}

public ClassX(A a){
  this(a, null);
}

public ClassX(B b) {
    this(null, b);
}
```

Comment: "*Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*". Explain your code please.

Comment: @Mistalis: I love the quote :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy already said in comment, there could be some code that calls the `private` constructor instead of the intended `public` ones.

Concerning the fix, I prefer a pattern where 1 (private?) constructor sets all variables, and other additional constructors call this "main" constructor, e.g.:

```
private ClassX(A a, B b){
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = createCSomehow();
}
public ClassX(A a){
  this(a, null);
}
public ClassX(B b) {
  this(null, b);
}
```

Comment: But in my case my variables were Data source and Connection pool. It have no sense to have them like parameters in same constructor because if I have constructors with some parameters I guess in some case all of them can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

What about the case where the constructor that takes no arguments is called, c is the only object variable that's being initialized. The object variables a and b only get initialized in the constructors that take arguments. So the fix should be as follows?

```
final A a;
final B b;
final C c = createCSomehow();

public ClassX() {
    a = null;
    b = null;
}

public ClassX(A a) {
    this.a = a;
    b = null;
}

public ClassX(B b) {
    a = null;
    this.b = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java all the final field must be initialize to some value. They can be assign value only once either where they are declared or in the constructor. 
If some final field is not initialize with declaration then it should be initialize in the all the constructor.